# How do I fetch multiple selected values from dropdown menu in jsp and use it in a controller method

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

How do I fetch the multiple selected values from the dropdown menu in `jsp` and use it in a controller method to populate a model class?

I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the fields to a POJO using ModelAttributes. Here is the example check it out.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

You can declare list for that particular field.